# Is there a way to change default chinese fonts in en_US lanugage system?

Tags: fonts, fontconfig, dwm

I'm using DWM as my window manager and my favorite font is `Source Code Pro`. So I set it as my DWM's font.
However, I always have some Chinese characters to display. But the Chinese character is so ugly on my UI. So is there a way to change only the Chinese fonts? By the way, I want to keep my system language English.

Comment: Does https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Fallback_font_order solve your problem?

Comment: It works! thank you, but the chinese font is much smaller than the English letters. But maybe that's a problem of dwm.